# How to Style React-Navigation tab navigator with a mobx variable

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx, mobx-react

I think I've just been staring at this too long, and now my brain doesn't work. I have mobx stores, one of which houses a basic theme color value. I want to pass this into my react-navigation tab background color, but I can't figure out how to do it. We are using Typescript, and that might be part of what is confusing me, because every time I try to inject my store, I get a bunch of errors.

Anyway, if someone could help me figure out how to either inject my store properly, or to pass a prop to my createMaterialTopTabNavigator function, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my top tab navigator code:

```
  export const SignedInWithGroup = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: MeetingStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Advocacy Day',
        tabBarIcon: <Ionicons name="md-home" size={24} />,
      },
    },
    Legislators: {
      screen: Legislators,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Legislators',
        tabBarIcon: <Ionicons name="ios-people" size={24} />,
      },
    },
    Messages: {
      screen: Messages,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Messages',
        tabBarIcon: <Ionicons name="ios-chatboxes" size={24} />,
      },
    },
    Directory: {
      screen: DirectoryStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Directory',
        tabBarIcon: <MaterialIcons name="contacts" size={24} />,
      },
    },
    More: {
      screen: MoreStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'More',
        tabBarIcon: <MaterialIcons name="more" size={24} />,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      style: {
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 0,
        backgroundColor: "#CCBE00", //Replace with theme color
      },
      tabStyle: {
        padding: 0,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 8 : 0,
        marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 10,
        marginLeft: 15,
        fontSize: 7,
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  }
);

export const createRootNavigator = (props:any, signedIn = false) => {
  console.log("Props");
  console.log(props);
  return createSwitchNavigator(
    { SignedInWithGroup: { screen: SignedInWithGroup }, SignedOut },
    { initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'SignedInWithGroup' : 'SignedOut' }
  );
};
```

and here is what is in my app.js:

```
    const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
    return (
      <Provider {...stores}>
        <Layout />
      </Provider>
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Use your custom tabbar from `MaterialTopTabBar`.

1. Install the `react-navigation-tabs` module. Because, react-navigation's `TabNaviagtion` is from `react-navigation-tabs`. ([srcs](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/master/src/index.js))

   $ yarn install `react-navigation-tabs`

   or

   $ npm install `react-navigation-tabs` --save
2. Make your custom tabbar component observing **store**(MobX) for the `tabBarComponent` option . I do not write code related in MobX or Redux.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MaterialTopTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

// create a component
class TabBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaterialTopTabBar
        {...this.props}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} // Replace with theme color. You should use observing variable from MobX or Redux. 
      />
    );
  }
}

//make this component available to the app
export default TabBar;
```

3. Apply your custom tabbar in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`.

```js
const TabNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Login: HomeScreen,
    Register: HomeScreen,
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: (props) => { // Use your custom tabbar here. 
      return (
        <TabBar
          {...props}
        />
      );
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      style: {
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 0,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        padding: 0,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 8 : 0,
        marginBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 10,
        marginLeft: 15,
        fontSize: 7,
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  }
);
```

## Why?

As I wrote, `react-navigation-tabs` is used as `TabNavigation` basically in `react-navigation` And you can use custom view through `tabBarComponent` option when you `createTabNavigator`

There are some mudules you can use.

#### Navigators

- createBottomTabNavigator
- createMaterialTopTabNavigator

#### Views

- BottomTabBar
- MaterialTopTabBar (You used this view)

#### Utils

- createTabNavigator

Thus, extending component or making your custom tabbar from `BottomTabBar` or `MaterialTopTabBar` can be one of the easily solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, and I really appreciate you going into so much detail to help me understand!

Comment: @shawleigh17 My pleasure :)

Comment: @JeffGuKang This saved my @$$! Have spent 2 weeks simply trying to pass in a parameter to change the height of my bottom Tab navigator. Created a simple custom TabBar derived from react-native's BottomTabBar and BOOM! Thanks